# How do get a random element from a List in Dart?

Tags: dart

How can I retrieve a random element from a collection in Dart?

```dart
var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```dart
import "dart:math";

var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

// generates a new Random object
final _random = new Random();

// generate a random index based on the list length
// and use it to retrieve the element
var element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
```

Answer (score 92):

This works too:

```
var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

//this actually changes the order of all of the elements in the list 
//randomly, then returns the first element of the new list
var randomItem = (list..shuffle()).first;
```

or if you don't want to mess the list, create a copy:

```
var randomItem = (list.toList()..shuffle()).first;
```

Comment: this doesn't mess with the whole list?

Comment: Yes, @GabrielDeOliveiraRohden, this actually changes the order of all of the elements in the list randomly, then returns the first element of the new list.

Comment: @Mason so this applies a effect to the original list and doesn't make a new one.. nice side effect to deal with after the shuffle call :D

Comment: Indeed, I've edited the answer to add a way not to mess the original list if needed, depending on what you want.

Comment: `shuffle` is a relatively expensive operation simply to select a random element. Use one of the other methods to stay in O(1) time.

Answer (score 31):

```
import "dart:math";

var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

list[Random().nextInt(list.length)]
```

Answer (score 14):

I just created an extension method for List.

```
import 'dart:math';

extension RandomListItem<T> on List<T> {
  T randomItem() {
    return this[Random().nextInt(length)];
  }
}
```

We can use it like this.

```
List.randomItem()
```

example :

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: isItLogin
            ? Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/53888-login-icon.json')
            : Lottie.asset(LottieAssets.loadingAssets.randomItem()),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: better handling: `T? getRandom() => isEmpty? null : length == 1 ? first : this[Random().nextInt(length)];`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [dart_random_choice](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_random_choice) package to help you.

```dart
import 'package:dart_random_choice/dart_random_choice.dart';

var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var el = randomChoice(list);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
list.elementAt(Random().nextInt(list.length));
```

Answer (score 6):

This is provided by the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)'s [IterableExtension.sample()](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/sample.html) method:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
print(list.sample(1).single);
```

Example output:

```
e
```

Note that the method is generalized to return *N* samples of the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'dart:math';

final _random = Random();

// from MIN(inclusive), to MAX(inclusive).
int randomBetweenIncInc(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt((max + 1) - min);

var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var element = list[randomBetweenIncInc(0, list.length - 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also we can create *CurrentStatu* likes Whatsapp in following code

*I used your answer , thx bro*

```
import 'dart:math';
void main(){

var list = [0,1];

//TODO  generates a new Random object with for()
final _random = new Random();
var element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];

Status Statuscurrent = Status.values.elementAt(element);
print(Statuscurrent);
}

enum Status{ 
online,
offline
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).