# How to select random element from a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a dart file with the list looks like

```
class Happylist {
  String imageUrl;

  String url;
  String name;

  Happylist({
    this.imageUrl,
    this.url,
    this.name,
  });
}

List<Happylist> hes = [
  Happylist(
    name: 'somename',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/someimage.jpg',
    url: 'someweblink',
  ),
  Happylist(
    name: 'somename',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/someimage.jpg',
    url: 'someweblink',
  ),
```

And intialized with object named hes,  so please help me to create a function in main.dart which generates the random element from that list.
When it generates a random element how to access its url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import math library to generate random int;

```
import 'dart:math';
```

here is a pseudo list;

```
List yourList = ["first item", "second item", "third item"];
```

and then create a random in that will be used as index should be limited max number with the list's size;

```
int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(yourList.length);
```

and check the result;

```
print(yourList[randomIndex]);
```

Comment: But my list conatins like this it contains two parameters both image url and url ,so please tell me how to select a random element from list and at the same time by tapping on it ,it should return its url.

Comment: here is live preview; https://codepen.io/malibayram91/pen/KKdmMVe

Comment: @Rahul It would help if you provided an example of what your data looks like and what you expect.  Given what information you provided in the question ("How to select random element from a list"), this answer would work.

Comment: this is my code 
class Happylist {
  
  String imageUrl;

  String url;
  String name;

  Happylist({
    this.imageUrl,
    this.url,
    this.name,
  });
}

List<Happylist> hes = [
  Happylist(
    name: 'somename',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/someimage.jpg',
    url: 'someweblink',
  ), so i want o select random element from that list .please help me

Comment: @Rahul 1. Put your code in your question, not in a comment. 2. This answer would let you pick a random a `Happylist` element from `hes`.  If it's not working for you, then you need to say how it doesn't work.

Comment: yes the answer worked but it picks just a random element ,but how can i get the parameter url of that particular element

Comment: @Rahul You'd get data from the random `Happylist` element the same way you'd get it from any other `Happylist` object. For example, `hes[randomIndex].url`.

Comment: But  when i tried to access with the hes[randomIndex].Imageurl,it showing error like unable to load asset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212525/discussion-between-rahul-and-jamesdlin).

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
List<Happylist> hes = List<Happylist>();

  hes.insert(
      0,
      new Happylist(
          name: 'somename',
          imageUrl: 'assets/images/someimage.jpg',
          url: 'someweblink'));
  hes.insert(
      1,
      new Happylist(
          name: 'somename1',
          imageUrl: 'assets/images/someimage1.jpg',
          url: 'someweblink'));
  hes.insert(
      2,
      new Happylist(
          name: 'somename2',
          imageUrl: 'assets/images/someimage2.jpg',
          url: 'someweblink'));

  var randomHappylist = (hes.toList()..shuffle()).first;
  print(randomHappylist.imageUrl);
```

[check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart)

Comment: means it return a element randomly can i get the url too.

Comment: this is my code 
class Happylist {
  
  String imageUrl;

  String url;
  String name;

  Happylist({
    this.imageUrl,
    this.url,
    this.name,
  });
}

List<Happylist> hes = [
  Happylist(
    name: 'somename',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/someimage.jpg',
    url: 'someweblink',
  ), so i want o select random element from that list .please help me

Comment: wait i will give answer

Comment: this is my problem i wnt to get the  particular image along with on tap that particular url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212526/discussion-between-rahul-and-chanaka-weerasinghe).

Comment: But when i tried to access with the hes[randomIndex].Imageurl,it showing error like unable to load asset

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: hello it can get zeroth insdex

Comment: What should i do to fix this