# How can I take random variables from Array in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, arraylist, random

I am new to flutter. I have one String Array and it has 20 values. However, I want to take 12 random values from this array and create a new array with this values. Can you show me the way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart

Comment: @AshKhachatryan I dont want to get just one element from list I need 12 variables to create new list

Comment: you can shuffle your array and get first 12. yourArray.shuffle()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart)

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var newList = [];

//adjust to you with 12
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // generates a new Random object
  final _random = new Random();
  

  // generate a random index based on the list length
  // and use it to retrieve the element
  int index = _random.nextInt(list.length);
  var element = list[index];

  //add the element to your new list and remove it to the old list
  newList.add(element);
  list.removeAt(index);
}
print(newList);
```