# How to get random digit from list

Tags: dart

Is there function to get quickly 1 digit from list?
For example List list = [0,4,8,12] and I want to set a new variable with one of them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do get a random element from a List in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart)

Comment: Why not use Math.random() and just make the function yourself? Pass the array.length as the max argument to Math.floor so the number returned is never larger than the arrays length.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like that:

```
List list = [0, 4, 8, 12];
var newVar = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
```