# flutter - how to display a random name from a list of names

Tags: list, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Please how do you display a random name from a list of names in flutter?
for example
List names = ['jerry','mark','john'];

how do i display a random name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do get a random element from a List in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this code:

```
import "dart:math";

List names = ['jerry','mark','john'];

// generates a new Random object
final _random = new Random();

// generate a random index based on the list length
// and use it to retrieve the element
var element = names[_random.nextInt(names.length)];
```

This method would also work:

```
var randomName = (names.toList()..shuffle()).first;
```

Credit to [How do get a random element from a List in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart)

Comment: I keep getting an error in the last line
var element = names . . . 
the "names" keeps giving error

Comment: This could be because the value passed to the nextInt method is inclusive, so could return 3, which would trigger an out of bounds exception.

Comment: I updated the code for that case but I tested it in dartpad and it was working fine

Comment: I added a second solution also

Comment: it should be `names[_random.nextInt(names.length)]` - the docs say: *"Generates a non-negative random integer uniformly distributed in the range from 0, inclusive, to max, exclusive."*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dart:math package and its Random object.  This will display a random name from your array every time the widget is rebuilt.

```
Text(names[Random().nextInt(names.length - 1)])
```

You will have to add

```
import 'dart:math';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number from 0 until the list size and then use it as a index to get a random element.