# How can I randomly add two users to a collection in firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently developing a chat application which allows users to chat with another random user by clicking a button. I have added the following package to my app: https://docs.flyer.chat/flutter/firebase/firebase-usage

My database looks as follows:

collection: rooms
document: chatroom1
subcollection: messages

collection: users
document: uid1 (which then includes fields like username, gender etc.)

So now I do not know how to get two random users from my users collection and create a chat room for them, in order to allow them to chat. How can I code the matching? And how do I create a chatroom for each random match? Is there a simple way?

Comment: Have you considered just doing it sequentially as users ask to join a chatroom? First one click would create the room and next user to click would check for open rooms that aren't full and create new room otherwise. I'd imagine it'd be fairly random unless you only have like 10 users total. This is basically how most if not all online matchmaking lobbies for games work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That's actually a smart idea! Do you have any idea how to implement this in code? What I don't know with this approach, is how to name the rooms and how I can actually implement a user "joining" a room - How would that look in code? And how can I make sure a user is only shown the messages from the room he has joined?

Comment: Using that package, unfortunately no

Comment: Any idea how to do it without this package?

Comment: You've got a bunch of questions in the question - please limit it to one question per post here on SO. My question(s) to you are a) Do you know how to select two random elements from an Array of elements and b) Do you know how to read data from Firestore? If the answer is yes and yes, then you are on your way - write some code and if you get stuck, post it. If not, see [Dart: Random Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart) and [Get Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Answer (score 2):

First You need to create a list of users(uid or the doc_id) like this

```
final list = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5'];
```

then when you are trying to start chat so you can select the opponent by using this method

```
// generates a new Random object

final _random = new Random();

// generate a random index based on the list length
// and use it to retrieve the element

var element = list[_random.nextInt(userList.length)];
```

so it is just a reference for you for getting randow user.
Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this. You will need to query your users collection to get a list of all users. Then, you will need to randomly select two users from that list and create a chat room for them.